# Node.js passing parameters to client via express render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Node.js and I'm having issues communicating with a client.

I define Express:

```
var express             = require("express");
var app                 = express();`
```

When I try and pass a parameter to the client upon requesting a page the variable holds no data, for example:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index", { name: "example" });
});
```

On the index page, when I use the console to print the variable (`name`)it returns `""`.

More info: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.render

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: it's just passing parameters in template

Comment: I'm using handlebars as my engine, how would I access the parameters then? Is it at all possible to just pass parameters that become locally available on the client's page?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The variable `name` you sent to the render function is only available while rendering the page, after it is sent to the client, it is not accessible. You have to use it in your view on the rendering stage.

Since you are using handlebars, you can display it in your page like this, for instance:

```
<h1>{{ name }}</h1>
```

If you want to use this data in a javascript, use it inside a `script` tag:

```
<script>
  var name = "{{ name }}";
  console.log(name);
</script>
```

Comment: When I console.log(name) I got {{ name }}

Comment: remove the quotes

Comment: For reference if anyone needs it, I am using the example at the following link to make a "simple template engine" and can return and capture a boolean value in the script tags with `#my_variable#` as shown above (without the quotes):  https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html

Comment: it works even if you are passing a .html file to `render()` and that html file loads another .js file with `<script src=...>`

Answer (score 9):

You are basically telling express to render your index page and providing a value for the `name` variable, but that doesn't necessarily make the `name` var available in your client side javascript. You need to edit your index template to display the `name` variable in the page.
The syntax varies depending on the templating engine you are using (jade, ejs, dustjs).

Another solution is to use an ajax call in your client page's javascript and use `res.json` on the server instead to send the data. Then you can evaluate `name` in the console. Ex using jquery:

index.html:

```
$.get( "/getvar", function( data ) {
  name = data.name;
});
```

server.js:

```
app.get("/getvar", function(req, res){
    res.json({ name: "example" });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get parameters on the clientside via javascript, you should do template like this `<script>var data = data</script>`, otherwise variables aren't available

If you use Jade, it will be something like this:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    var name = !{name}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Passing data list from node js to html**

**server.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path    = require("path");

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');

var __dirname = "D:/html-files";
var app = express();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

var engine = require('consolidate');

app.engine('html', engine.mustache);
app.use(express.static('./'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    res.render('index.html');   

});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
   console.log("Got a POST request for the homepage");
   res.send('Hello POST');
});

app.post('/get-user-list', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {

    let db = new sqlite3.Database('user.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
        console.log('Connected to the user database.');
        console.log("ID" + "\t" + "NAME" + "\t" + "EMAIL");
    });

    db.serialize(() => {     

        var dataList = "";

        db.each('SELECT id, name, email FROM USER ', (err, row) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
            }
            if(dataList != "")
            dataList = dataList + ',';

            dataList = dataList + '{"id":"' + row.ID + '","name":"' + row.NAME + '","email":"' + row.EMAIL + '"}';
            console.log("dataList : " + dataList);
        });

        db.close((err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
            }
            console.log('Close the database connection.');
            response = {'username':dataList};                           
            aFunction(res, dataList);

        });

    });

});

var aFunction = function(res, dataList) {
    console.log('return to page.');
    console.log("dataList : " + dataList);
    res.render(__dirname + "/list-all-users.html", response);
};

app.listen(8081, '127.0.0.1')
```