# Can my node.js program get the npm version number?

Tags: html, node.js, npm, version

I have a Node.js web application that uses the version number (when a request from a client asks for the version number). For now, when I change my version, I have to change it in three places:

## In `server.js`

```
const version = 'v1.2.3'
```

## In `package.json`

```
"version": "1.2.3"
```

## In `doc.html`

```
<h1>version 1.2.3</h1>
```

Is there a way to edit it in one place and use it in the others?

*Note*: `server.js` and `doc.html` are related like this:

```
// in server.js, using express
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/doc.html')
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js passing parameters to client via express render](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328028/node-js-passing-parameters-to-client-via-express-render)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a 2-steps problem:

**1) Pass parameters from `package.json` to `server.js`**

`server.js`:

```
const version = require('./package.json').version
```

**2) Pass parameters from `server.js` to `doc.html`**

1. Install a template engine. I'll take ejs for the sake of this example: `npm install --save ejs`.
2. Rename your `doc.html` to `views/doc.ejs`.
3. Insert `<%= version %>` in your HTML file where you want the version to be.
4. Modify `server.js` so it looks like this:

`server.js`:

```
const version = require('./package.json').version

//...

app.set('views', './views')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

//...

app.get('YOUR URI', function(req, res) {
  res.render('doc.ejs', { version: version })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could execute shell command `npm version`, which will give you

```
{ 
  nameOfYourService: '1.2.3',
  npm: '3.10.6',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV'
  //etc
}
```

Then just read value for `nameOfYourService`, and pass it as a variable to render the view (in case of html) or just use it in your `server.js`

In this case `package.json` is the only place where you keep your version number, and rest of the app just reads it from there.

Comment: Thanks, I found out it was a duplicate and that the chosen answer from the other question is amazingly simple to implement.