# How can I apply the Heroku generated server port to my front-end Vue.js app?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, vue.js

This problem is similar to a more general question of communicating between server and client, however the issue is probably heroku specific because the server port is provided by heroku in the 'process.env.PORT' variable.

My back-end express/mongoDB app has been deployed on heroku. It listens on the assigned port = process.env.PORT which is a new port every time the server starts

The front end Vue.js runs on the same express server and uses axios for CRUD

I have tried port = process.env.PORT || 4000 in the Vue application but it is always 4000 so the request fails.

Is there some way to pass the port number from the backend Node.js environment to Vue.js components ?

It appears that process.env.PORT is not set in the Vue.js application

Extract from a sample Vue component

.
.
.

```
import port from '../config';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tokens: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    let uri = 'http://localhost:' + port + '/tokens';
    this.axios.get(uri).then(response => {
      this.tokens = response.data;
    });
  }
};
```

.
.
.

'config.js'

```
const port =  process.env.PORT || 4000;

export default port;
```

'server.js' segment

```
const PORT = 4000;
const port = process.env.PORT || PORT
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Express server running on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js passing parameters to client via express render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328028/node-js-passing-parameters-to-client-via-express-render)

Comment: Are you using vue cli? also process.env is something provided by node am unsure how you can access it at the client. Also when making axios call at client all we have to do is give '/tokens' we need not give localhost+port, etc  if client/server configs are properly set they would be able to talk to each other with relative path since ideally it would be running on same host.

Comment: yes I am using vue cli. You made a very good point about using the relative path. I will try that. I used the full path because I saw that in an example.  I agree that process.env is not accessible from the client.

Comment: Thanks very much Gowri. That was the perfect answer.  Many of the tutorials I have seen include the full path because the client may be running on a different server.

Comment: @DesAlbert glad my suggestion solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks very much to Gowri for an excellent response that completely fixed the problem.

For newcomers to Vue who follow the many tutorials that have been published, please take note of the need to use a relative path when deploying to heroku. My MEVN app is now working perfectly.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tokens: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    let uri = '/tokens';
    this.axios.get(uri).then(response => {
      this.tokens = response.data;
    });
  }
};
```