# Error while trying to give name to homepage

Tags: node.js, express

How to give homepage name as home page and render data of index file. But while trying to do so it gives me error.

Server.js::

```
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.end('Home page')
    res.render('index')
});
```

Error:

```
  [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the page title as a second argument to the res.render function

```js
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'Home Page'})
});
```

Comment: It s not giving me any output. Only giving me data of what was in the index part. But doesnot display the title as I require

Comment: @Ajax could you share a repository/sandbox example of your set up?

Answer (score 0):

By executing `res.end()` you already sent header to the client, so you can't edit after sending to client.

Comment: So how can I edit I followed the solution by @Ahmed F. but it doesnot display the title only the content of the index file

Comment: okay inside the index page, you will be able to use title, this is depending on the view engine you are using, if ejs or bug.

Comment: this link should help you to get it better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328028/node-js-passing-parameters-to-client-via-express-render