# Storing sessions of user visits on a single page

Tags: node.js, express

Trying to: Create a single page web application that uses sessions to store the time when the
client last visited the web page. If this is the first visit, then display This is your first visit!
Otherwise, print The last time you visited this page was …. The dots should be replaced by the
date and time the user last visited this page.

It doesn't seem to run at all and I cant figure out why ?

Code so far:

```
var express = require('express'),
    handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({defaultLayout: 'main'}),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    sessions = require('express-session');

var app = express();

app.use(sessions({
    secret: 'secretString',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 },
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

let date_ob = new Date(seconds);
let date = date_ob.getDate();
let month = date_ob.getMonth() + 1;
let year = date_ob.getFullYear();
let hours = date_ob.getHours();
let minutes = date_ob.getMinutes();
var visited = year + "-" + month + "-" + date + " " + hours + ":" + minutes;
// prints date & time in YYYY-MM-DD format
console.log(year + "-" + month + "-" + date);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sessions.Assignment3Cookies = visited;
    res.send(["The last time you visited this page was" + " " + req.sessions.Assignment3Cookies]);
    res.render('main');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate');
});
```

Comment: Hey, Welcome to Stack Overflow - It's hard to tell what your question is from the content of this post. Please review these guidelines if you'd like to get better responses to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey, Welcome to Stack Overflow - It's hard to tell what your question is from the content of this post. Please review these guidelines if you'd like to get better responses to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if (req.session.Assignment3Cookies) {
        // either send or render here YOU CANNOT HAVE BOTH
        res.send(["The last time you visited this page was" + " " + req.sessions.Assignment3Cookies]);
    } else {
        req.session.Assignment3Cookie = visited;
        res.send(["The last time you visited this page was" + " " + req.sessions.Assignment3Cookies]);
    }
});
```

If you want to use `res.render()` take a look at this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328028/), you can pass variables from `javascript` to your `template`

***And as always have fun coding.***